# VMware vCSA 6.5 SSO: Cannot get "Enhanced authentication plug-in" working for any browser, multiple PC's

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I have successfully setup SSO with my .LOCAL domain and I can login if I type the credentials, but I cannot get the "Enhanced authentication plug-in" working for any browser, and have tried 2 PC's now. I'd like to use Chrome, but would settle for IE (at least as a start). **The "Use Windows session authentication" checkbox is grayed out.** I have also tried:

- Ensuring Chrome is allowing ALL permissions to https://vcsa-6.5.mydomain.local/vsphere-client/?csp
- Tried HTML5 client in IE11
- Uninstall re-install the EA plug-in on both machines.

What could be the issue here? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it!

1. Uninstall any and ALL vSphere thick-clients!
2. Uninstall VMware Enhanced authentication plug-in 6.5 & VMware plug-in service
3. Reinstall the above 2 plug-in's and ensure the service is running: VMware CIP Message Proxy Service

That's it. Open your browser, navigate to vSphere web console login and VMware CIP Message should prompt to allow now.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome ver 45 or older (2015). Then web client from 2017 will allow you to use windows authentication. Not secure. A simple throw in browser's backyard, no thought for the customer. If C client was available, we could only upgrade it once on each management workstation and get to our duties, securely.